# Querying serialized object file

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there anyway to achieve that without loading the whole file into memory? If so, what do you suggest me to do?

Class implementation:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Car
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class CarCollection : List<Car>
{
}
```

Serialization to file:

```
CarCollection cars = new CarCollection
{
    new Cars{ Brand = "BMW", Model = "7.20" },
    new Cars{ Brand = "Mercedes", Model = "CLK" }
};

using (Stream stream = File.Open("data", FileMode.Create))
{
    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
    bin.Serialize(stream, cars);
}
```

Comment: Is it serialized to XML?

Comment: @Groo nope, it is not serialized to XML. I've added the class implementation to my question.

Comment: Serialization doesn't actually load the binary file in memory, it goes through the stream and deserializes it on the fly. But after this is done, entire object is loaded into memory, which makes me think you would like to load only a part of it. Which part would that be? A single property? And when you say "querying", do you refer to LINQ querying? Because there should be a collection of objects in that case, which is not visible from your code.

Comment: The objects are stored in a collection then saving to a file with simple serialization. I want to make a linq query without loading whole collection into memory. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible, update the question with the code you are using to serialize it to make it easier to understand how it looks like (those line where you use a `BinaryFormatter` or something similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deserialize the collection one object at a time, you also need to serialize it one at a time.

Simplest way is to define your own generic class:

```
public static class StreamSerializer
{
    public static void Serialize<T>(IList<T> list, string filename)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();

            // seralize each object separately
            foreach (var item in list)
                bin.Serialize(stream, item);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Deserialize<T>(string filename)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();

            // deserialize each object separately, and 
            // return them one at a time

            while (stream.Position < stream.Length)
                yield return (T)bin.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply write:

```
CarsCollection cars = new CarsCollection
{
    new Cars{ Brand = "BMW", Model = "7.20" },
    new Cars{ Brand = "Mercedes", Model = "CLK" }
};

// note that you cannot serialize the entire list if
// you want to query without loading - it must be symmetrical

StreamSerializer.Serialize(cars, "data.bin");

// the following expression iterates through objects, processing one 
// at a time. "First" method is a good example because it
// breaks early.

var bmw = StreamSerializer
    .Deserialize<Cars>("data.bin")
    .First(c => c.Brand == "BMW");
```

A slightly more complex case might be if your `CarsCollection` belongs to a different class. In that case, you will need to implement [`ISerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx), but the principle is similar.

On a side note, usual convention is not to name entities in plural (i.e. `Cars` should be named `Car`).

Answer (score 2):

If you serialize to XML you can use a SAX parser ([XmlReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)), which will read from a stream seqentially.

Comment: i don't prefer to serialize to XML. What if i choose JSON serialization?

Comment: @onatm: Yes, [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializingJSONFragments.html) allows this, using [`JObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use some sort of reader (StreamReader, BinaryReader, ...) together with BufferedStream.